# Multiple actions for with_items

Tags: ansible

I am trying to perform multiple actions for each database instance, specifically configure a crontab entry.

Here is my hosts entry:

```
hkxtsdbdv1 ansible_host=hkxtsdbdv1.alpha.lftltd.net instances='["XTS_DEV","XTS_UAT","XTS_OPT"]'
```

And here is the playbook I am trying to run:

```
- hosts: "{{hosts}}"
  tasks:
      - name: add_cron_entries
        with_items: "{{ instances }}"
        cron: name="RMAN {{item}} Archivelog Backup" minute="0" hour="*" job="cron.sh rman.pl {{item}} archivelog"
#        - cron: name="RMAN {{item}} Database Backup" minute="0" hour="0,4,8,12,16,20" job="cron.sh rman.pl {{item}} database"
#        - cron: name="RMAN {{item}} Database Backup" minute="0" hour="1" weekday="0" job="cron.sh rman.pl {{item}} validate"
```

I've tried various ways to get this working, but struggling, not sure if is because of my lack of understanding of YAML, or Ansible (or both).
Could anybody help me out please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all separate tasks that happen to be iterating over the same list. As such you want to break your tasks up like this:

```
- hosts: "{{hosts}}"
  tasks:
      - name: archivelog backup cron
        with_items: "{{ instances }}"
        cron: name="RMAN {{item}} Archivelog Backup" minute="0" hour="*" job="cron.sh rman.pl {{item}} archivelog"

      - name: database backup cron
        with_items: "{{ instances }}"
        cron: name="RMAN {{item}} Database Backup" minute="0" hour="0,4,8,12,16,20" job="cron.sh rman.pl {{item}} database"

      - name: database backup validation cron
        with_items: "{{ instances }}"
        cron: name="RMAN {{item}} Database Backup" minute="0" hour="1" weekday="0" job="cron.sh rman.pl {{item}} validate"
```